# Need help on trying to add the len(item) as an index.

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some data and I think I found the solution but I'm struggling with writing the code for it.

```
# This returns a list that changes depending on the page     
description = response.xpath('.//*[@class="txtGrey size14-description"]/text()').extract()
```

I need to get the exact len(description) and have that length added as an index for the description (not sure if I am using the word index correctly)

So for example

```
description = response.xpath('.//*[@class="txtGrey size14-description"]/text()').extract()

len(description)
```

if length of description is 4

the code needs to say

```
description = response.xpath('.//*[@class="txtGrey size14-description"]/text()').extract()[-4:]
```

note: I need the '-' and ':' in there.

I will be scraping through several pages so the len is always changing. I'm assuming I need to write a new function for this. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please give example of description and the wanted output for that description as it is not clear how exactly you will use len

Comment: Whatever len was I was going to use that to index description. I'm running into a snag where when I output the scraped data as a csv the "description" cells are always empty. though when I used [-1:] as an index those with only 1 list in description would appear and the rest would not appear. I'm hoping that by using the exact len I would be able to get all the descriptions working.

Comment: still without example unclear what are you actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Use variable instead of constant there :

So first step just extract the len() of your description and save that len to a variable :

```
len_= int(response.xpath('.//*[@class="txtGrey size14-description"]/text()').extract())
```

Then just check by `if` condition :

```
if len(len_)==4:
```

If above condition is true then execute below code :

Second step now use that variable as index_no for slicing :

```
description = response.xpath('.//*[@class="txtGrey size14-description"]/text()').extract()[-len_:]
```

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. I was trying to concatenate len_ by doing '[' + len_ + ':]' . If you have the time can you explain to my why I was unable to concatenate it that way? Anyways thank you for your help =)

Comment: @DanielAhn if my solution helped you can [accept the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @DanielAhn you do realise that when you do this you are getting the same result as simply using extract() without any additional code? As the two other answers tell you, x[-len(x):] == x

Comment: @Gnudiff i forgot the condition , i have updated it.

Comment: Yes I do realize it now lol. After trying the solution the csv file that was exported still had blank cells. I'll have to do more debugging as to why it isn't outputting correctly. I'm now assuming it is because I am outputting it as a csv because when I output as a json the description information shows while on the csv it just appears as blank cells.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
my_list[-len(my_list):]
```

will always return the original list (a copy, actually), since

```
my_list[-x:]
```

means "get the last `x` elements of `my_list`", and you're setting `x` to the number of elements in the list, so it gets all of them.

For example:

```
In [1]: my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [2]: my_list[-len(my_list):]
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Overall, it's not very clear what you're asking here. Could you rephrase your question?

Answer (score -1):

```
# This returns a list that changes depending on the page     
description = response.xpath('.//*[@class="txtGrey size14-description"]/text()').extract()
```

To find the length

```
len(description)
```

Suppose length is 4. So doing what you are doing will again return the same list again

```
description = response.xpath('.//*[@class="txtGrey size14-description"]/text()').extract()[-4:]
```

## Here is an example to make it clear :

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> len(a)
9
>>> a=a[-(len(a)):]
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print(a[-9])
1
```

This is because [-9] points to the starting of the list and [-9:] therefore indicates the starting to the end of the list or the complete list again.